# Improve mysql query for comments 2-tier hierarchy

Tags: mysql, performance

There is a table with comments in format

```
|  ID  |ID_PARENT| ...
```

If parent is equal 0 then it is root comment, children has references to parents.

There are 2 levels of comment hierarchy only. So, parent comments and all answers to it as second level.

It is selected in 2 queries currently:

- parents by id (autoincrementing) first

  ```
  select id, txt
  from comments
  where id_parent = 0
  order by id desc limit 500
  ```
- then all id's from first query are stored in array and query for children is, i.e.

  ```
  select id, txt, id_parrent
  from comments
  where id_parent in (58286, 55857, 54242, 53937, 53770, 52825, 51765, 51204, 50996, 50810, 44735, 43680, 43576, 42336, 41440, 41157, 39715, 38973, 38614, 36560, 36331, 36099, 35819, 35280, 33950, 33607, 33503, 32802, 30689, 27807, 27712, 26821, 25895, 23927, 23485, 23433, 22709, 22706, 22252, 21203, 20293, 20041, 19824, 19619, 19560, 19233, 17209, 17129, 16879, 16822, 16602, 14060, 13992, 13986, 13137, 13074, 12294, 10729, 10698, 10690, 10689, 10687, 10679, 10677)
  order by id_parent desc, id asc
  ```

Then there is iteration over parents with selection children from result of second query.
Sometimes there are 500 id and it looks terrible...

Is there any optimizations possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should get all those comments in 1 go, sorted with parents preceding their children in id order.

```
SELECT case when parent_id = 0 
THEN parent_id
ELSE id
END as sort_id, comments.* FROM comments ORDER BY sort_id, parent_id, id ASC
```

Is that what you were trying to do?

If you have access to the way things are saved, and can change the parent_id value to NULL when it's a top-level comment, you could make this query a lot quicker by doing:

```
SELECT IFNULL(parent_id, id) as sort_id, comments.*
FROM comments ORDER BY sort_id, parent_id, id ASC
```